# Google App Maker: how to implement pagination on table bound to a calculated model

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a calculated Model and in the UI I have added a table widget that is bound to this model. The data loads fine but the pagination and sorting does not work. How to I wired up this functionality?

Comment: Pagination is not working for calculated models in the app maker according to the app maker support team. See their comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305663/google-app-maker-how-to-add-pagination-and-sorting-to-a-table-widget-bound-to-a

Comment: The Support Group is not AppMaker support, they're a seperate company

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @IanHyzy